# Is it best practice to wrap LinearLayouts / RelativeLayouts / etc. with ScrollView just to be safe?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

With all the various screens sizes (both portrait and landscape) is it best to wrap conventional layouts (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLinear`, etc) with a `ScrollView` if there is even the possibility of content extending  below the screen?  Is there a better approach?

Update Question:  What about custom inflated Views?  Does the same approach apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I would go as far as saying that wrapping every `LinearLayout` with a `ScrollView` is a "best practice".

That said, in my own experience, I have often created layouts that use `ScrollView` + `LinearLayout` even when I know that my content will fit on most phones. I've done this because (1) I want to support both portrait and landscape orientations (and landscape often does not have enough height to display everything) and (2) because I want to support any device my users might have (and some people do have really tiny phones).

The trick is to differentiate between cases where your `LinearLayout` is just chopping the screen up into pieces vs cases where your `LinearLayout` is a parent to some number of views each with their own fixed height. Two `Button`s next to each other, each taking 50% of the screen width, obviously don't want a `ScrollView` around them. But a form of eight `EditText` fields on top of each other might do well to be wrapped in a `ScrollView`, even if all eight fit on your personal device's screen just fine.

The downsides to having an "extra" or "useless" `ScrollView` on larger phones is so tiny that I've never worried about it. A single extra `View` instance isn't going to hurt performance or use up too much extra memory. The upside of making your app usable on tiny screens, though, is well worth it.

Comment: Thanks, this was my sense as well.  See my additional question about Custom inflated views.  I'd appreciate your thoughts on that as well.

Comment: I'd say basically the same thing about custom views. If the view is made of things "stacked" on each other (like the EditText form example), wrapping in a ScrollView will often make sense (assuming it's more than like 150dp tall). If the view is just a custom component like a row of Buttons, then no need.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible cases:
If your layout is a static layout, just buttons, text views etc., then you can just preview different screen sizes within Android studio and verify that the layout works fine for the devices you support. 
If your layout is dynamic, like ListView, RecyclerView that gets dynamic data set, it is always a good idea to make ScrollView as the parent.

Does that answer your question? Please reply if further explanation is needed.

Comment: ListView should never be placed in a ScrollView, and RecyclerView shouldn't need to be (since it provides scrolling on its own).

Comment: @BenP.  I agree to your point. It is it just a RecyclerView or a ListView  in a layout, we shouldn't wrap with ScrollView. But if we were to have other views in addition to these, it is a good idea to wrap in a ScrollView.